# scala (spark) zio convert future to zio

Tags: scala, apache-spark, zio

My objective is to run a number of spark ml regression models (1000s of times) on one dataset and I want to do this  using zio instead of future, because it is running too slow. Below is the working example of using Future. 
A distinct list of keys is used to filter the partitioned dataset on key and run the model on. I've set up a thread pool with 8 executors to manage it, but it quickly degrades in performance.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, ExecutionContextExecutorService, Future}
import java.util.concurrent.{Executors, TimeUnit}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8)
implicit val xc: ExecutionContextExecutorService = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(pool)

case class Result(key: String, coeffs: String)

try {

    import spark.implicits._
    val tasks = {
    for (x <- keys)
        yield Future {
        Seq(
            Result(
            x.group,
            runModel(input.filter(col("group")===x)).mkString(",")
            )
        ).toDS()
            .write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("header", false).csv(
            s"hdfs://namenode:8020/results/$x.csv"
            )
        }
    }.toSeq
    Await.result(Future.sequence(tasks), Duration.Inf)
}
finally {
    pool.shutdown()
    pool.awaitTermination(Long.MaxValue, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
}
```

I've tried to implement this in zio, but I don't know how to implement queues and set a limit of executors like in futures.

Below is my failed attempt so far...

```
import zio._
import zio.console._
import zio.stm._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

//example data/signatures
case class ModelResult(key: String, coeffs: String)
case class Data(key: String, sales: Double)
val keys: Array[String] = Array("100_1", "100_2")
def runModel[T](ds: Dataset[T]): Vector[Double]

object MyApp1 extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val input: Dataset[Data] = Seq(Data("100_1", 1d), Data("100_2", 2d)).toDS

  def run(args: List[String]): ZIO[ZEnv, Nothing, Int] = {

    for {
      queue <- Queue.bounded[Int](8)
      _ <- ZIO.foreach(1 to 8) (i => queue.offer(i)).fork
      _ <- ZIO.foreach(keys) { k => queue.take.flatMap(_ => readWrite(k, input, queue)) }
    } yield 0
  }

  def writecsv(k: String, v: String) = {

    Seq(ModelResult(k, v))
    .toDS
    .write
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("header", value = false)
    .csv(s"hdfs://namenode:8020/results/$k.csv")
  }

  def readWrite[T](key: String, ds: Dataset[T], queue: Queue[Int]): ZIO[ZEnv, Nothing, Int] = {

    (for {
      result <- runModel(ds.filter(col("key")===key)).mkString(",")
      _ <- writecsv(key, result)
      _ <- queue.offer(1)
      _ <- putStrLn(s"successfully wrote output for $key")
    } yield 0)
  }
}

//to run
MyApp1.run(List[String]())
```

What is the best way to deal with compute this in zio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parallelize some workload across, say, 8 threads all you need is

```
ZIO.foreachParN(8)(1 to 100)(id => zio.blocking.blocking(Task{yourClusterJob(id)}))
```

But don't expect lots of a boost by switching from Futures to ZIO here:

1) Actual workload dominates coordination overhead so difference between `ZIO` and `Future` should be marginal.

2) Maybe you won't get any boost at all because 8 tasks will be fighting for the same resource pool in the Spark cluster.

Comment: thanks! yeah you're right with points 1 and 2. i've taken a different approach to this problem now, as spark ml is too slow for this type of work.